# what are the jboss-client.jar maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, dependencies, jms2

I'm building a JMS Topic application with maven. 
I'm using wildfly 9 (and JMS 2.0) and I need to use de jboss-client.jar provided by wildfly to make the application work (It's a simple Publisher-subscriber application).

Since I'm using maven, I want to put all my dependencies on the pom.xml, however I can't find the right dependency for the jboss-client.jar.
I tried several "jboss-as-client" dependencies, but something is always missing for the rest of my JMS imports.

Any ideia how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-client-all</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```